# Dlink DWA-131 + r8712u (+ hostapd + nl80211 wireless AP) is that possible?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, opensuse

I'm trying to make my OpenSUSE desktop box work with a DLink wireless N Nano adapter. Additionally I'd like to make it the access point for my laptop.

The problem is - when I run `hostapd` (with r8712u kernel module loaded via `modprobe`) it fails with the following message:

```
nl80211 not found.
nl80211 driver initialization failed.
```

OKay, when I tried (my mistake) to use `rtl8192se PCI driver` it could find `nl80211` (needed `compat`-wireless for that though) but failed with a message about cannot create mon.wlan0 interface blah-blah

I'm pretty sure that I missed something because that device was reported to work with OpenSUSE 11.4 out of box.

Maybe that `r8712u` driver kernel module does not properly load all the needed dependency modules and I could `modprobe` them manually?

EDIT: I did `modprobe mac80211` and now hostapd fails with following message:

```
Failed to create interface mon.wlan0.
nl80211 driver initialization failed.
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that my wifi dongle cannot work in `monitor` mode as needed by `hostapd`. Anyway the `r8712u` driver was just freezing my whole system whenever it connected to an `ad-hoc` network. Maybe more luck with new kernel or ndiswrapper but I'm off for now because I'm tired :]